# Bijective Functions, solution check.

Tags: functions

I have 3 functions here, for which I must determine whether or not they are bijective.

1 : f(x) = $x^2$     f : is a function from R to +$R^0$ ( positive real numbers without 0 Is how I understood the notation, and + is a lower index for R )

my solution : f is not a bijection because it is not an injection, for example f(-1) = 1, and f(1) = 1 aswell

2 : f(x) = $x^2$      f : is a function from (0,1) to +$R^0$

my solution : f is not a bijection, because it is not a surjection, there is an infinite number of images in +$R^0$ that do not get mapped into anything.

3 : f(x) = $x^2$ f : is a function from (0,1) to (0,1)

my solution : yes, f is a surjection, because it is both injective and surjective

i : injective because every part in the first set gets mapped to one part in the second set

ii : surjective because every image in the second is mapped.

Is this correct?

Comment: You should give proofs for 3i) and 3ii), they are easy.

Comment: "yes, f is a surjection, because it is both injective and surjective" is a silly thing to say - the fact that its injective is irrelevant for it to be surjective since $(0,1)$ is an infinite set so injective does not tell you about surjective-ness, and then the remaining sentence is then a tautological.